# Import and save with same cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am importing different workbooks into one workbook with succes but I can't save it with the same cell value. It seems to skip the `Range("D2:E3").text` part at the save.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Path = "\\ap01\data\Reports\Scrap WHS02\Scrap History\"
fileName = Dir(Path & Range("D2:E3").Text & "*_02*.xlsx")
Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open fileName:=Path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop

Dim sfileName As String
sfileName = "\\ap01\data\Reports\Scrap WHS02\Scrap History\" & Range("D2:E3").Text & "_02 Scrap.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=sfileName, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: I don't usually use `.text` when I use a saveas macro, just the range.

Comment: `.value`you mean? I have tried this but it returns in error or do i have to remove the `Dim`?

Comment: Just the range is all I use. Looking at the code, are you trying to saveas a workbook onto a sharepoint server?

Comment: No its saved on an other computer in our network. It does save it but the name of the file is _02 Scrap.xlsx.

Comment: is `Range("D2:E3")` a merged cell?

Comment: Then I try `Range("D2:E3").Text` in immediate window, the result is : **1)** `<Text>` only if all of the cells contain same text. **2)** `Null` if just one of the cells contains other text (including blank).

Comment: so `Range("D2:E3")` is not merged?

Comment: Range was merged, thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be with the merged cell.
When I use this it will work, it will not work with the merged cells range("D2:E3")

```
Dim sfileName As String
sfileName = "C:\TestFolder\" & Range("D2") & "_02 Scrap.xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sfileName
```

Try to avoid using merged cells in code.

Answer (score 0):

I've read in a French website to call the file using `Dir` without `()`. Therefore, in the loop change `fileName = Dir()` with `fileName = Dir`.

Comment: @Erik, I believe the problem is with the save part of the code not the loop.

Comment: @Gerry I thinked that  Dir with parenthesis reload folder content and not passed to next files